# How to validate phone number in react that until user give valid phone number button should disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
export default function Validate() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [disable, setDisable] = useState(false);
  function handleChange(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value.length <10)
     {
      setDisable(true);
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      Phn:<input error={disable} type="number" value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>
      <button disabled={!disable}>click</button> 
    </>
  );
}
```

in this case initially button is disabled but when i type one number button is enabled but i need untill user give 10 digit phone number button is disabled

Comment: Your condition in disabled is wrong, you are saying that !disable, when it should be just disable, since it will be disabled when the disable variable is true

Comment: if i write in this way that disabled={disabled.length<10} its also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from "react";
export default function Validate() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [disable, setDisable] = useState(true);
  function handleChange(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setDisable(value.length !== 10);
  }, [value])
  return (
    <>
    Phn:<input error={disable} type="number" value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>
    <button disabled={disable}>click</button> 
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Check this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-solomon-3nyfk

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

I have added the link to the code
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-ikqdn?file=/src/input.js

**Go to `https://ikqdn.csb.app/input` in `codesandbox browser`**

---

What you are missing in the code is

```
function handleChange(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value.length <10) <-- not updating the disable if length = 10
     {
      setDisable(true); 
    }
  }
```

and in the `input` and `button` error and disable

```
Phn:<input error={disable} type="number" value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>
<button disabled={!disable}>click</button>
```

Both are in alternative state, i.e. if one becomes valid, then other becomes invalid.

---

Initially `disabled` must be `true` because input is empty and

I have taken initial value of `input` as `null` as an indicator of not clicked.

**This is the condition of `input` error**
*Input is clicked and the length != 10*

```
value !== null && disable
```